# Safe mutation and usage of readonly property value in Objective-C APIs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, convention, declared-property

Consider a C++ API like `const T* foo()`. This clearly documents the supported mutability and use of the API: *OK, we'll let you look at T, but please don't change it*. You *can* still mutate it, but you have to explicitly use `const_cast` to indicate your intention to not follow the API.

A good portion of Objective-C API's are comprised of property declarations. How is a user of an API *supposed to interpret*: `@property (readonly) T foo` ? (Assume T isn't an immutable type)

- Since the setter isn't synthesized, clearly `foo` isn't mean to be **replaced**.
- However, the getter still gives me a pointer to `foo`. Is it safe to mutate foo? (Clearly I *can*)

**NOTE:** I'm not asking about the language specs. I'm asking about what the conventional interpretation of an API like this is within the Objective-C community.

Comment: "Clearly I can" Not necessarily. Many important Objective C classes are immutable. And for exactly this reason. Thus, for example, a read-only NSString property is neither settable nor mutable. All you can do is look at it, just as you say.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your response. OK. So If I have an object I want to work with internally, but want to let users of my API look at it, is the convention to wrap it in an immutable type and return that in some function? I.e. In the cases where the property *isn't* an immutable type, even if the property attribute is `readonly`, I can still safely assume the API designer supports mutability?

Comment: Just a heads up this may get flagged as off topic as you are asking for opinions and not a solution to a problem you are having. I would suggest looking at one of the stack exchange communities for this type of question as the moderators will very likely flag it here on Stack Overflow

Comment: @jammie no you can't assume the designer supports mutability, a quick example would be to look at UIButton and setting the Title/Text of a button. The reference for button is immutable but you can change the text of the Label object which represents the Title. But UIButton provides an method setTitle:ForState: which implies to me, that you are not supposed to touch the label directly but instead are supposed to set it via the supplied methods and allow the object to manage it's properties.

Comment: @CStreel Thanks for the repose. This is very unfortunate. A poor API design I think. At least their discussion indicates usage?

Comment: Rule of Thumb: If a property is read-only, respect it as read-only. Which I think should be universal across any language, even if you have the ability to change somethings mutability

Comment: @CStreel Ok thank you. Clearly "read-only" is potentially ambiguous given the specification of the language. This is why I needed to ask the question, because of the generally understood "read only", and Objective-C language implementation of their property declarations. But again, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103159/discussion-between-cstreel-and-jammie).

Comment: Join the chat in the link, I actually want to discuss this further because I find it interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [matt said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330271/safe-objective-c-api-usage#comment58368707_35330271), the fact that you've got a pointer to the object does not mean that the object itself is mutable. Objective-C uses the behavior of the class, not the pointer, to enforce immutability. So in general you should be seeing read-only properties that return, e.g., `NSString` rather than `NSMutableString`.

I took a look through Apple's iOS framework headers to verify this:

```
grep -rn "@property.*readonly.*Mutable" /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/*.h
```

(The pattern for class names in Cocoa is to call the mutable "version" of the class `$PREFIXMutable$CLASSNAME`: `NSString`/`NSMutableString`, `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary`.)

> ./System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Headers/AVComposition.h:133:@property
>   (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<AVMutableCompositionTrack *> *tracks;
>   ./System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Headers/NSManagedObjectContext.h:149:@property
>   (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSMutableDictionary *userInfo
>   NS_AVAILABLE(10_7,  5_0);
>   ./System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:54:@property
>   (readonly, retain) NSMutableString *mutableString;
>   ./System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSExpression.h:127:@property
>   (readonly, copy) id (^expressionBlock)(id __nullable, NSArray *,
>   NSMutableDictionary * __nullable) NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
>   ./System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSThread.h:24:@property
>   (readonly, retain) NSMutableDictionary *threadDictionary;
>   ./System/Library/Frameworks/GameplayKit.framework/Headers/GKRuleSystem.h:54:@property
>   (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSMutableDictionary *state;
>   ./System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Headers/MDLMesh.h:137:@property
>   (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSMutableArray *submeshes;

Only seven results, and the one in `NSExpression` doesn't count because the "Mutable" that the search found is an argument to the Block that is actually the property's value.

For the others, I think you'll find that the appropriate class reference doc tells you what you can and can't do with the values.

For example, the [documentation for `threadDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSThread/threadDictionary) has this to say:

> You can use the returned dictionary to store thread-specific data.[...]You may define your own keys for the dictionary.

A mutable dictionary is returned precisely so that you *can* mutate it. The thread object doesn't let you set it, however, so that it can also store things there.

The hit in NSAttributedString.h is actually in the `NSMutableAttributedString` class, and [those docs note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableAttributedString/mutableString):

> The receiver tracks changes to this string and keeps its attribute mappings up to date.

Since `NSAttributedString` is pretty explicitly* just an `NSString` packaged up with a bunch of attributes, the design of the class exposes the wrapped string directly; the mutable version follows suit.

`UIButton` was mentioned in the comments, because there you have a read-only label whose own properties are modifiable. And there again, [the docs are explicit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel):

> Although this property is read-only, its own properties are read/write. Use these properties primarily to configure the text of the button.

and

> Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color.

In summary, there's no way in Objective-C at the language level to create or enforce mutability restrictions. As you've noted, a property marked `readonly` simply means there's no way for you to set the value to something else.** And there's no equivalent of `const_cast`ing the value to be mutable so that you can change it: you will end up with a new value that the vendor object knows nothing about.

The *Cocoa* convention, then, is to secondarily enforce the property's status by using immutable classes. (In some cases you might even be getting an immutable copy of data that the class internally retains as mutable.) If the API gives you a mutable object, you can assume that you may mutate it, but **the documentation should tell you exactly how you can use it**.

---

*Its [class description says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/): "An `NSAttributedString` object manages character strings and associated sets of attributes (for example, font and kerning) that apply to individual characters or ranges of characters in the string."

**There is KVC, but that's again at the framework level, and framework convention would indicate that you're asking for trouble doing that.

Comment: Dude. Awesome response. +100

Comment: Thanks, glad I could be helpful.